# Getting Hebrew Nikud on the letters on Android

Tags: android, unicode

I have a text in Hebrew, with Nikud (see the actual text [here](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%99)). When I put it in an Android application, the dots come out after the letters (See picture below). Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

[image: Hebrew Niukud is after letters, not on it]

Comment: Did you find a solution?